# AEM with TarMK Cold Standby Not working

Tags: aem, jackrabbit, jackrabbit-oak

I am trying to configure AEM with TarMK Cold Standby. I have followed the below urls to configure

https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/deploy/recommended-deploys/tarmk-cold-standby.html
http://cq-ops.tumblr.com/post/102621710969/how-to-configure-an-aem-6-cold-standby-failover

But i am getting java.lang.IllegalStateException :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException:Attempt to read external blob with blobId
[c184d2a3f1dbc709004a45ae6c5df7624c2ae653#32768] without specifying BlobStore
  at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentBlob.getReference(SegmentBlob.java:118)
  at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentWriter.writeBlob(SegmentWriter.java:706)
  at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentWriter.writeProperty(SegmentWriter.java:808)
  at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentWriter.writeProperty(SegmentWriter.java:796)
```